# Install UBUNTU MINIMAL to external HDD

Tags: drivers, partitioning, system-installation, usb-drive, ubuntu-minimal

I am trying to install UBUNTU minimal to a Seagate 1TB external HDD. I have disconnected my internal drive so that this installation doesn't conflict with Windows 7. But I am experiencing problems as the setup is not detecting my external drive. Instead it shows no disk drive was detected and asks me to choose the correct drivers. Although it does detect my 16GB HP pendrive.

My first partition on HDD is NTFS file format and Primary. Second partition is 20gb ext4 then I have about 300GB unallocated space. Further I have 3 logical partitions. Again I have about 4GB unallocated space.

I downloaded the amd64 version of mini.iso from official site and it is the latest version.

Do I need some drivers to install to external USB hdd ? When I select none of the above in the driver selection menu I do get the option to load the missing drivers from removable media.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting so long for an answer, I decided to install UBUNTU to my 16GB pendrive, however the setup was unable to install grub bootloader so I installed it myself following the guide : http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Then I used dd to create a disk image. And restored the image to external HDD partition and installed bootloader to the external HDD. And now I have successfully booted into UBUNTU and I wrote this answer in UBUNTU.

If UBUNTU setup is unable to read the partitions on external HDD then repartition the entire drive. This always solves the issue.